# How to keep the loop running and send all the messages?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send more than 1000 messages. The problem happens in the twilio catch: when an error returns, the loop breaks and does not continue to advance. How can I keep the loop running and thus ensure the sending of all messages?

```
try {
        const targets: TargetSms[] = data.targets;
        const rbd = data.rbd;
        const idMessage = data.idMessage;

        const messageRef =  admin.firestore().collection(`/RBD/${rbd}/messages`).doc(idMessage);
        await messageRef.set({ serverResponse: true }, { merge: true });


        let countSeg = 0;
        for (const target of targets) {
            if (target.messagePayload) return target;
            const textMessage = {
                body: target.plainMsg,
                to: target.targetNumber,  // Text to this number
                from: twilioNumber, // From a valid Twilio number
            };

            const payloadMessage  = await client.messages
                .create(textMessage)
                .then(mess => mess)
                .catch(err => {
                    console.warn('ocurrio un error al enviar mensaje', err)
                    target.messageError = err;
                    return null;
                });

                if(payloadMessage){
                    countSeg = countSeg + parseInt(payloadMessage.numSegments);
                    target.messagePayload = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new MessagePayload(payloadMessage)));
                }
            await admin.firestore().collection(`/RBD/${rbd}/targets`).doc(target.id).set(target);
            await timeout(100);
        };

        await messageRef.set({totalSegments:countSeg},{merge:true});
        await admin.firestore().doc(`/RBD/${rbd}`).set({config: {"countSms": admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(countSeg)}},{merge:true});


        return JSON.stringify({ suss: true, message: 'Mensajes enviados' })

    } catch (error) {
        return JSON.stringify({ suss: false, message: error })
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to reformat your code a little bit, something like:

```js
for (const target of targets) {
    if (target.messagePayload) return target;

    const textMessage = {
        body: target.plainMsg,
        to: target.targetNumber,  // Text to this number
        from: twilioNumber, // From a valid Twilio number
    };

    let payloadMessage;
    try {
        payloadMessage  = await client.messages.create(textMessage);
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn('ocurrio un error al enviar mensaje', err)
        target.messageError = err;
        // continue;  // Remove this line to continue the execution of finally block
    } finally {
        if (payloadMessage) {
            countSeg = countSeg + parseInt(payloadMessage.numSegments);
            target.messagePayload = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new MessagePayload(payloadMessage)));
        }

        await admin.firestore().collection(`/targets`).doc(target.id).set(target);
        await timeout(100);
    }
};
```

In this way you can get rid of the "old" `then` syntax, because `async - await` lets you to put your `await` code inside a `try - catch` block to intercept the errors from the `await` call, and everything else after will be executed in case of success.

Also use `continue` to instead of `return null`.

Maybe you can get rid of the conditional block `if (payloadMessage)` because `try - catch` ensures that your variable has a value, but idk for sure.

Specs here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: `client.messages.create(textMessage)` is the same as `client.messages.create(textMessage).then(res => res)`, Does that assure me that the payload of the message returns?

Comment: Kind of, when you use `client.messages.create(textMessage).then(res => res)`, the return value of `client.messages.create(textMessage)` is the `res` variable inside `then`. But `await` let you to assign the value to a variable directly, this is why `then(res => res)` is irrelevant.

Comment: when it captures an error the cache does not continue the lines below, it skips to the next index of the loop, `countSeg = countSeg + parseInt(target.messagePayload.numSegments);` it does not run if the error is

Comment: Yes, the catch stops the execution if an error is thrown by the `await` call. If you need that the code continues the execution after the catch, you can add a finally block after the catch, answer edited...

Comment: You can also simply comment the `continue`, in this case you don't need a finally block.

Comment: I tested the code with 600 messages. but more than 3000 messages were sent, something happened that the loop is repeated since the user arrived at least 15 times the message

Comment: I recommend debugging your variables because the for cycle should only iterate over the elements in the targets variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `continue` statement to "continue" processing items after an error in your loop.

[continue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)

Comment: This is wrong, you can't continue a for loop inside the catch arrow function, as the for loop is out of scope from within the catch handler.

Comment: E.g., `for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) (() => continue)();` will throw a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @junvar Exactly, is within the date, the same editor notifies me of that error